# How to turn rows of a variable into columns with occurrence and grouped_by?

Tags: r, dplyr, group-by, pivot

I have a dataset that looks like this

```
Group| School
11-12  Middle School
8-10   Elementary 
5-8    Elementary
5-8    Elementary
8-10   Elementary
14-16  High School
11-13  Middle School
```

How do i turn it into

```
 Group|Elementary|Middle School|High School
 5-8            2             0          0
 8-10           2             0          0
11-12           0             1          0
11-13           0             1          0
14-16           0             0          1
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can use `table` from `base R` which gives the frequency table in a `matrix/table` class

```
table(df1)
```

---

Or if we need a tidyverse option

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)
df1 %>%
  pivot_wider(names_from = 'School', 
    values_from = 'School', values_fn = length, values_fill = 0)
```

---

Or with `dcast` from `data.table`

```
library(data.table)
dcast(setDT(df1), Group ~ School, fun.aggregate = length, fill = 0)
```

Comment: Yeah I wanted to get like in the second version. Than you once again akrun.